# Windows Batch: Copy child folders including files to different location

Tags: windows, batch-file

The structure is like this: 
`c:\parent\level1\level2\`

- The `level1` folder is empty
- the `level2` folder contains a lot of folders with files in it.

The goal is to copy all folders in `level2` to a different folder, lets say `c:\test` but by keeping the original name of the folder:

```
c:\parent\level1\level2\folderwithfiles1\
c:\parent\level1\level2\folderwithfiles2\
```

The `folderwithfiles1` and `folderwithfiles2` need to be copied to a different location (including the files that are in those folders).

Now the challenge: the name of the `level1`, `level2` and `folderwithfilesX` folder is variable (because these are automatically extracted folders).
I hope it's clear like this.

Answer (score 0):

As best as I understand what you are trying to do isn't this just a case of `robocopy /mir c:\parent\%l1%\%l2% c:\test` which will take all files and subfolders of level2 and below and copy them to c:\test?  You may prefer /e rather than /mir depending upon what is in c:\test.

Comment: I came up with this myself, it does what it has to do, but it's in 2 steps, anyone know how I can combine this?:
`@echo off
for /d %%a in ("C:\parent\folder1\*") do robocopy.exe "%%a" C:\test\test /s /xf`
This copies the subdirectories en files to C:\test\test and then
`@echo off
for /d %%a in ("C:\test\test\*") do robocopy.exe "%%a" C:\test\test2 /s /xf
`
copies the previous copied folders and files to C:\test\test2.

Comment: Please *do not* post code snippets in comments in the sake of its readability: [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32177979/edit) instead.